# HttpClient PostAsync for JSON

Tags: c#, json, windows-8, http-post, httpclient

I am trying to use the Google OAuth and I have the first part done but now it want's me to POST the following:

> code= client_id= client_secret= redirect_uri= grant_type=authorization_code

Currently I am trying to do:

```
var http = new HttpClient();
http.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
var response = await http.GetStringAsync(uri);
```

That will send but get an error back as it's requesting I do Post sending (could use PostAsync) but I have no content to send to "POST" and it's supposed to return a JSON Feed...

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the code, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri etc values? If so, you could post that?

Comment: The information is actually generated once you login via the API and then it provides a "token" in which you run via the required URI fields (above).